# Xquery program to transform a soap message

Tags: soap, transform, message, xquery

I'm new to xquery so please keep that in mind when responding but please do respond. i've been trying to solve this for a week and have found the xquery help out there to be spotty at best.

**i have written the following xquery program:**

```
declare namespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
declare namespace soap-env = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
declare namespace ns0 = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/GPDSND/SP_GET_PART_ATTRIBUTES/";
declare namespace com = "com:companyname:part:partspecification:partfinder:types:partschema:1:0";
<soapenv:Envelope>
<soap-env:Body>
<com:PartDetailResponse>
{
for $x in doc("soap.xml")/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns0:OutputParameters/ns0:P_CURSOR/ns0:Row
return $x
}
</com:PartDetailResponse>
</soap-env:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**which produces the following output:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Body xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <com:PartDetailResponse xmlns:com="com:companyname:part:partspecification:partfinder:types:partschema:1:0">
         <Row xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/GPDSND/SP_GET_PART_ATTRIBUTES/"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
            <Column name="PARTNUMBER" sqltype="CHAR">20831727</Column> 
            <Column name="BROADCASTCODE" sqltype="CHAR">1727U</Column> 
            <Column name="DRAWINGNUMBER" sqltype="CHAR">20831727</Column> 
            <Column name="MAKEFROMPART" sqltype="CHAR"/> 
         </Row>
      </com:PartDetailResponse>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**but i want the `<Column>` detail lines in the following format:**

```
<com:Column FieldName="PartNumber" DisplayName="Part Number" ToolTip="String" ContentType="String"><com:Value>20875646</com:Value></com:Column>
<com:Column FieldName="BroadcastCode" DisplayName="Broadcast Code" ToolTip="String" ContentType="String"><com:Value>     </com:Value></com:Column>
<com:Column FieldName="DrawingNumber" DisplayName="Drawing Number" ToolTip="String" ContentType="String"><com:Value/></com:Column>
<com:Column FieldName="MakeFromPart" DisplayName="Make From Part" ToolTip="String" ContentType="String"><com:Value>20875634</com:Value></com:Column>
```

so how do i change the format of the detail lines? my hunch is the partschema should have something to do with it yet it's embedded within a SOA service so i'm not sure if i'm actually getting to it due to the fact that i'm not passing any credentials to clear the authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Use element construction like you already did for pasting the output into the template.

```
for $x in doc("soap.xml")/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns0:OutputParameters/ns0:P_CURSOR/ns0:Row
return <com:Column FieldName="{$x/@name}" [...]><com:Value>{data($x)}</com:Value></com:Column>
}
```

For the fields missing add some statements to calculate them or how to add them from your original data.

Comment: i was able to get the desired output but converting the fields and the values of the fields required hardcoding which i hate to do. what is a better way of getting the detail lines to covert to the format shown in my original post?

Comment: Where could you get the alternative formats from? "All caps" means fewest information, every other format (apart from all small or random capitalization) needs to get information from somewhere else. Maybe you could split at several words, have a look at [functx](http://www.functx.com/) for some xquery function library containing string processing. To process all lines, use an inline-flowr-expression.